# ArgumentError: The method .group() must contain arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm running the `counter_culture` gem, v1.6.2 (upgrading to 1.7 isn't an option for me currently) with Rails 5.0.2. I've got a `Contact`, `ContactGroup` and a `Group` model, like so:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :contact_groups
    has_many :groups, through: :contact_groups

    counter_culture [:contact_groups, :group], touch: true
    counter_culture [:contact_groups, :group],
        column_name: :confirmed_count,
        column_names: { ["contacts.confirmed_at IS NOT NULL"] => 'confirmed_count' },
        touch: true
end

class ContactGroup < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :contact
    belongs_to :group
    validates_uniqueness_of :contact_id, scope: :group_id
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :contact_groups
    has_many :contacts, through: :contact_groups
end
```

From what I understand from reading the docs, this setup is correct. If I run `Contact.counter_culture_fix_counts`, everything works fine. If I try to create a new contact, like so, I get the following error.

```
c = Contact.new(attrs)
[9] pry(main)> #<Contact id: nil, first_name: "Billy", last_name: "The Kid", email: "bkid@example.com" ...>
c.valid?
[10] pry(main)> true
c.save
[11] pry(main)> c.save
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
Contact Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."email" = 'bkid@example.com' LIMIT 1
Contact Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."email" = 'bkid@example.com' AND "contacts"."company_id" = 94 LIMIT 1
Contact Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."preferences_token" = '6dc8b7943f87efd81477450c199e6ecf' LIMIT 1
SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "contacts" ("first_name", "last_name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "company_id", "color", "encrypted_password", "confirmation_token", "confirmation_sent_at", "unconfirmed_email", "request_email_frequency", "invite_email_sent_at", "preferences_token", "key") VALUES ('Billy', 'The Kid', 'bkid@example.com', '2017-07-20 18:24:16.880278', '2017-07-20 18:24:16.880278', 94, '#344B59', '$2a$10$baAhoJtROfmJRx1ymb7aX.5s/5u.99..fT9OsC9MvoKEpmT4olq.G', '6dc8b7943f87efd81477450c199e6ecf', '2017-07-20 17:50:50.005270', 'bkid@example.com', 'Daily', '2017-07-20 17:50:50.033649', '6dc8b7943f87efd81477450c199e6ecf', 'Billy-dedf62') RETURNING "id"
(0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
ArgumentError: The method .group() must contain arguments.
from /Users/ACIDSTEALTH/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:1214:in `check_if_method_has_arguments!'
```

I've been struggling to figure out what's causing this for some time and so far my only working theory is that there is a name clash with my model `Group` and ActiveRecord's `.group()` method. I'm considering renaming `Group` to something else, but that's obviously a lot of work, so I'd like to first find out if my theory is correct, if possible. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have used a preserved word `group` in defining relation

`belongs_to :group` creates conflict with ActiveRecord's `group` method http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group.

The only solution is to use different name for the relationship

Comment: This is as I suspected unfortunately. I set up a new branch and changed my `Group` model to `Team`, which sure enough solved this issue. Thanks!